# When the uibutton wobbles it pushes uibuttons near itself

Tags: ios, uibutton

I added wobble function to my 2 buttons. The `startWobble` and `stopWobble` methods work properly:

```
- (void)startWobble {
_hint1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-10));
_hint2.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-10));

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.001
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)
                 animations:^ {
                     _hint1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(10));
                     _hint2.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(10));
                 }
                 completion:NULL
 ];
}

- (void)stopWobble {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear)
                 animations:^ {
                     _hint1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     _hint2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }
                 completion:NULL
 ];
}
```

However, I tested my app on the simulator, and when the buttons start to wobble they push the other buttons near themself.The buttons then stop to wobble everything looks fine again. I can't figure the problem out. I've used these methods and never faced a problem like this before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use automatic layout?

Comment: No i dont use automatic layout. Just checked it to be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'they push the other buttons near themself'? Do you mean their frames spread apart, or they highlight each other like a user is tapping them? Please elaborate.

Comment: I mean, their frames spread apart.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your issue. I copied your code verbatim and I'm not seeing any frame movement. I'm only seeing wobble rotation. Are you sure you aren't changing the frames of the buttons anywhere else?

Comment: Im pretty sure. As i mentioned in the question, i've used these methods and never faced a problem like this before.

Comment: Are you sure _hint1 and _hint2 are pointing to the right views?